# Refresh SQLite data on ListView with CursorAdapter

Tags: android, listview, android-sqlite, android-adapter

[image: Cant Refresh ListView and TextView]

**The app:** I have an app that creates multiple machines with:

- *_id, name and location*

each of these machines I have to let the user input the income

- *_id, note, date, money, machines_id*

**The Problem:** Can't refresh **ListView AND TextView** simultaneously after **OnLongClickListener**.

**What I have tried:** Cursor Adapter, swapCursor.

**My Question:** What is the best approach to accomplish the update of both things simultaneously in the same activity?

If you need any other class or have any feedback, please dont hesitate to indulge me!

**DBHelper**

```
    public class DBHelpter extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String DB_NAME = "machines.db";
    private static final int DB_VERSION = 1;

    public static final String TABLE_MACHINES = "machines";
    public static final String MACHINES_COLUMN_NAME = "name";
    public static final String MACHINES_COLUMN_LOCATION = "location";
    public static final String MACHINES_ID = "id";

    public static final String TABLE_INCOME = "income";
    public static final String INCOME_COLUMN_MONEY = "money";
    public static final String INCOME_COLUMN_DATE = "date";
    public static final String INCOME_COLUMN_NOTE = "note";
    public static final String INCOME_ID = "id";
    public static final String INCOME_COLUMN_MACHINES_ID = "machines_id";

    private Context mContext;

public DBHelpter(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
    }

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String query1 = String.format("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_MACHINES + "("
        + MACHINES_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
        + MACHINES_COLUMN_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
        + MACHINES_COLUMN_LOCATION + " TEXT NOT NULL)",
            TABLE_MACHINES, MACHINES_COLUMN_NAME, MACHINES_COLUMN_LOCATION, MACHINES_ID);

    String query2 = String.format("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_INCOME + "("
        + INCOME_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
        + INCOME_COLUMN_MONEY + " REAL NOT NULL, "
        + INCOME_COLUMN_DATE + " DATE NOT NULL, "
        + INCOME_COLUMN_NOTE + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
        + INCOME_COLUMN_MACHINES_ID + " INTEGER NOT NULL)",
            TABLE_INCOME, INCOME_ID, INCOME_COLUMN_MONEY, INCOME_COLUMN_DATE, INCOME_COLUMN_NOTE, INCOME_COLUMN_MACHINES_ID);
    db.execSQL(query1);
    db.execSQL(query2);

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    String query1 = String.format("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_MACHINES);
    String query2 = String.format("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_INCOME);
    db.execSQL(query1);
    db.execSQL(query2);
    onCreate(db);

}
public void insertNewMachine(String name, String location){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(MACHINES_COLUMN_NAME, name);
        values.put(MACHINES_COLUMN_LOCATION, location);
        db.insertWithOnConflict(TABLE_MACHINES, null, values, SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_REPLACE);
        db.close();
    }
public void insertNewIncome(Double money, String date, String note, long machines_id){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(INCOME_COLUMN_MONEY, money);
        values.put(INCOME_COLUMN_DATE, date);
        values.put(INCOME_COLUMN_NOTE, note);
        values.put(INCOME_COLUMN_MACHINES_ID, machines_id);
        db.insertWithOnConflict(TABLE_INCOME, null, values, SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_REPLACE);
        db.close();
    }
public void getIncomeOfMachine(long machinesId){
        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT machines_id, SUM(money) AS total FROM income WHERE machines_id = "+machinesId+"", null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    double total_amount = cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndex("total"));
    return total_amount;
    }
public ArrayList<MachinesClass> getAllMachines(){
        ArrayList<MachinesClass> machinesList = new ArrayList<>();
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+ TABLE_MACHINES, null);
        while (cursor.moveToNext()){
            final long id = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(MACHINES_ID));
            final String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MACHINES_COLUMN_NAME));
            final String location = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MACHINES_COLUMN_LOCATION));
            machinesList.add(new MachinesClass(id, name, location));
        }
        cursor.close();
        db.close();
        return machinesList;
    }

public void deleteIncome(long id){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete(TABLE_INCOME, INCOME_ID+ "=?", new String[]{id + ""});
    db.close();
}

public Cursor getInfoOfMachine(long machinesId){
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT _id, note, date, money FROM income WHERE machines_id = "+machinesId+" ORDER BY date ASC",null);
    return cursor;
}
```

**CursorAdapter**

```
public class ListAdapter extends CursorAdapter {


public ListAdapter(Context context, Cursor c) {
    super(context, c);
}

public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    return LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.notes_list, parent, false);
}

@Override
public void bindView(View view, final Context context, final Cursor cursor) {

    final DBHelpter mDBHelper = new DBHelpter(context);

    TextView mNote = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvNote);
    TextView mNotesDate = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvFecha);
    TextView mMoney = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvMoney);
    RelativeLayout mRelativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.rlNotesList);

    final Long id = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id"));
    String note = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("note"));
    String date = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("date"));
    double money = cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndex("money"));

    mNote.setText(note);
    mNotesDate.setText(date);
    DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("$#,##0.000");
    String formatted = formatter.format(money);
    mMoney.setText(formatted);

    mNote.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(v.getContext())
                    .setTitle("Confirmación")
                    .setMessage(Html.fromHtml("Segura de "+"<b>"+"BORRAR"+"</b>"+" la información?"))
                    .setNegativeButton("No", null)
                    .setPositiveButton("Si", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            mDBHelper.deleteIncome(id);
                            notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                    })
                    .create();
            alertDialog.show();
            return true;
        }
    });

}
```

}

**MachineInfo**

```
public class MachineInfo extends AppCompatActivity implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>{

private TextView mLocation, mMoney;
private DBHelpter mDBHelpter;
private ListView mNotesList;
private FloatingActionButton mFAB;
private SQLiteDatabase db;
private Cursor mCursor;
private ListAdapter mAdapter;
private Context mContext;
private static final int LOADER_INTEGER = 1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_machine_info);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    mDBHelpter = new DBHelpter(getApplicationContext());
    db = mDBHelpter.getWritableDatabase();

    mLocation = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvLocation);
    mMoney = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvMoney);
    mFAB = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fabAddIncome);
    mNotesList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvNotes);

    SharedPreferences mSharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    final Long machines_id = mSharedPreferences.getLong("machines_id", 0);

    double total_amount = mDBHelpter.getIncomeOfMachine(machines_id);
    DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("$#,##0.000");
    String formatted = formatter.format(total_amount);
    mMoney.setText(formatted);

    String location = mSharedPreferences.getString("location", null);
    mLocation.setText(location);

    mAdapter = new ListAdapter(this, mDBHelpter.getInfoOfMachine(machines_id));
    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    mNotesList.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    getLoaderManager().initLoader(LOADER_INTEGER, null, this);

    mFAB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), IncomeCreation.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
}


@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    SharedPreferences mSharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    final Long machines_id = mSharedPreferences.getLong("machines_id", 0);
    String[] projection = new String[]{"_id", "note", "date", "money"};
    String selection = "machines_id = "+machines_id;
    String sortOrder = "date ASC";
    return new CursorLoader(this, IncomeProvider.CONTENT_URI, projection, selection, null, sortOrder);
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor) {
    mAdapter.swapCursor(cursor);
}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
    mAdapter.swapCursor(null);
}
```

}

**IncomeProvider**

```
public class IncomeProvider extends ContentProvider {

private static final int INCOME = 1;
private static final int INCOME_ID = 2;
private static final String PROVIDER = "tech.destinum.machines.incomeprovider";
static final Uri CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse("content://"+ PROVIDER + "/income");
public static final UriMatcher mUriMatcher = new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);
static{
    mUriMatcher.addURI(PROVIDER, "income", INCOME);
    mUriMatcher.addURI(PROVIDER, "income/#", INCOME_ID);
}
private DBHelpter mDBHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase db;


@Override
public boolean onCreate() {
    Context context = getContext();
    mDBHelper = new DBHelpter(context);
    SQLiteDatabase db = mDBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return (db == null)? false:true;
}

@Nullable
@Override
public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {
    SQLiteQueryBuilder queryBuilder = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
    queryBuilder.setTables(DBHelpter.TABLE_INCOME);

    switch (mUriMatcher.match(uri)) {
        case INCOME:
            break;
        case INCOME_ID:
            queryBuilder.appendWhere(DBHelpter.INCOME_ID + "="
                    + uri.getLastPathSegment());
            break;
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URI: " + uri);
    }

    SharedPreferences mSharedPreferences = getContext().getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    final Long machines_id = mSharedPreferences.getLong("machines_id", 0);
    db = mDBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    projection = new String[]{"_id", "note", "date", "money"};
    selection = "machines_id = "+machines_id;
    sortOrder = "date ASC";
    Cursor cursor = queryBuilder.query(db, projection, selection,
            selectionArgs, null, null, sortOrder);

    cursor.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(), uri);
    return cursor;
}

@Nullable
@Override
public String getType(Uri uri) {
    return null;
}

@Nullable
@Override
public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues values) {
    int uriType = mUriMatcher.match(uri);
    SQLiteDatabase sqlDB = mDBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    long id = 0;
    switch (uriType) {
        case INCOME:
            id = sqlDB.insert(DBHelpter.TABLE_INCOME, null, values);
            break;
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URI: " + uri);
    }
    getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
    return Uri.parse("income" + "/" + id);
}

@Override
public int delete(Uri uri, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
    int uriType = mUriMatcher.match(uri);
    SQLiteDatabase sqlDB = mDBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    int rowsDeleted = 0;
    switch (uriType) {
        case INCOME:
            rowsDeleted = sqlDB.delete(DBHelpter.TABLE_INCOME, selection,
                    selectionArgs);
            break;
        case INCOME_ID:
            String id = uri.getLastPathSegment();
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(selection)) {
                rowsDeleted = sqlDB.delete(
                        DBHelpter.TABLE_INCOME,
                        DBHelpter.INCOME_ID + "=" + id,
                        null);
            } else {
                rowsDeleted = sqlDB.delete(
                        DBHelpter.TABLE_INCOME,
                        DBHelpter.INCOME_ID + "=" + id
                                + " and " + selection,
                        selectionArgs);
            }
            break;
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URI: " + uri);
    }
    getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
    return rowsDeleted;
}

@Override
public int update(Uri uri, ContentValues values, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
    int uriType = mUriMatcher.match(uri);
    SQLiteDatabase sqlDB = mDBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    int rowsUpdated = 0;
    switch (uriType) {
        case INCOME:
            rowsUpdated = sqlDB.update(DBHelpter.TABLE_INCOME,
                    values,
                    selection,
                    selectionArgs);
            break;
        case INCOME_ID:
            String id = uri.getLastPathSegment();
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(selection)) {
                rowsUpdated = sqlDB.update(DBHelpter.TABLE_INCOME,
                        values,
                        DBHelpter.INCOME_ID + "=" + id,
                        null);
            } else {
                rowsUpdated = sqlDB.update(DBHelpter.TABLE_INCOME,
                        values,
                        DBHelpter.INCOME_ID + "=" + id
                                + " and "
                                + selection,
                        selectionArgs);
            }
            break;
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URI: " + uri);
    }
    getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
    return rowsUpdated;
}
```

}

Comment: What do you meaqn by  - Can't refresh ListView AND TextView simultaneously after OnLongClickListener ?  I mean which TextView are you talking about

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try to use [Loaders](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html).

They let's you bind the data source (Content Provider or other) with the Activity or Fragment. While Loaders are active they should monitor the source of their data and deliver new results when the contents change.

I'll give you a general approach to how implement them (CursorLoader in particular) :

```
public class MachineInfo extends AppCompatActivity implements
    LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

    private static final int LOADER_INTEGER = 1;

    // ... existing code

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        getLoaderManager().initLoader(LOADER_INTEGER, null, this);
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
        return new CursorLoader(
            this,
            ContentProvider.CONTENT_URI,
            projection,
            null,
            null,
            sortOrder
        );
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor) {
        mCursorAdapter.swapCursor(cursor);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
        mCursorAdapter.swapCursor(null);
    }
}
```

You can read a lot on internet about this, a good start is for example [here](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-fundamentals-properly-loading-data--mobile-5673).

Hope this helps

Comment: Sorry for the long delay, I did created a **ContentProvider** and it does not yet refresh the list. Going to post my other classes. Thanks for trying to help tho

Comment: When you call mDbHelper.deleteIncome(id), is your method delete (inside content provider) called? And, I can't see the method deleteIncome inside your DBHelper

Comment: **Method included** now. I did not call the **delete method** inside the content provider because I want to emulate **SQLite** raw query ""SELECT _id, note, date, money FROM income WHERE machines_id = "+machinesId+" ORDER BY date ASC"

Comment: Try to do this after executing the raw delete : `if ( returnNum != 0 )
            getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri,null);` where `int returnNum = db.delete(...)`

Comment: I think it is not updating because you are not notifying the loader, so you have to do it when you delete some rows.

Comment: Also, an alternative way to do this raw delete is to: send the query nornally to the content provider `getContext().getContentResolver().delete(yourUri,whereClause,selectedArgs);` and let the delete method inside ContentProvider catch this specific query. Once this is done you can do your raw query from inside the contentProvider

Comment: So i have to delete from both **SQLite** and **ContentProvider**?

Comment: Watching your Content provider, I suggest you to not do the raw queries outside content provider standard methods (query, update, insert, delete), Because inside these methods you are notifying the Loader to Observe specific URI, so I suggest you to call the content provider standard methods, catch the query you want to do e do the query as you want (normal or raw)

Comment: @Ispam, no you don't have to delete them, you should change them

Comment: Im still trying to grasp it. I did changed the query method of the provider to fit what i needed and the CursorLoader method 2.

Comment: Using ur answer "getContext().getContentResolver().delete(yourUri,whereClause‌​,selectedArgs)" managed to refresh the list. BUT still cant refresh the TextView of the total amount.

Comment: I forgot this. Which id?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135708/discussion-between-ispam-and-valentino-s).